# How to keep elements sorted when unmarshalling XML

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

In XML the order of the elements has an importance

I have the following XML:

```
<s>
    <a toto="toto"/>
    <b data="data"/>
    <a toto="tata"/>
    <b data="doto"/>
</s>
```

with

```
type S struct {
    As      []A      `xml:"a"`
    Bs      []B      `xml:"b"`
}
xml.Unmarshal(MyXML, &S)
```

I can get all the data from my XML, the A are sorted and the B too but I have no information about the global order because the A and the B are sorted in different arrays.

Is there a way to get the global order of elements? (I have no control over the XML data)

Answer (score 0):

I think , there is no such thing on "encoding/xml", as by the inner elements are different fields in the xml structure:

```
<a toto="toto"/>
<b data="data"/>
```

One alternative for this behavior are implement the
[xml.Unmarshaller interface](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Unmarshaler) on your final struct and decode the xml fields by hand, keeping then as a array of same type.

Something like this:

```golang
type Child struct {
    Value   string
    TagName string
    Toto    string
    Data    string
}

type S struct {
    Fields []Child
}
```

And implement the Unmarshaler:

```golang
func (s *S) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    c := Child{}
    for {
        // Token returns the next XML token in the input stream.
        // At the end of the input stream, Token returns nil, io.EOF.
        t, _ := d.Token()

        switch tt := t.(type) {

        case xml.StartElement:
            c.TagName = tt.Name.Local

            if c.TagName == "a" {
                c.Toto = tt.Attr[0].Value
            }
            if c.TagName == "b" {
                c.Data = tt.Attr[0].Value
            }

        case xml.CharData:
            c.Value = string(tt)

        case xml.EndElement:
            if tt.Name.Local == c.TagName {
                s.Fields = append(s.Fields, c)
                c = Child{}
            }

        case nil:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Running code: [Playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/lTF5ilDEhHD)

This is just an example , but I think it might be a naive alternative for your situation.

Comment: What would you do if the inner element would be the same?

Comment: Just do normal xml mapping  [Playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/H6dpm53ZL-C).